# Power series and power expansion with absolute convergence.

Tags: power-series, generating-functions, absolute-convergence

> Suppose $|a|+|b|<1$ and absolutely convergent. How can I show
> $$
> \frac{1}{1-a-b} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{(1-b)^{n+1}}?
> $$

I tried to start from here:
$$
\frac{1}{1-a-b}=\frac{1}{1-(a+b)}=\sum_{m,n}{m+n\choose n}a^nb^m
$$
then I tried to use the fact that we have absolute convergence but haven't gone nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

One possible direction to look at is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{(1-b)^{n+1}}
 = \frac{1}{1-b} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{(1-b)^n}
 = \frac{1}{1-b} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{a}{1-b}\right)^n
$$
and you can use the geometric series on the sum for $|a| < |1-b|$.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. Could you take a look at this problem (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853213/using-cauchy-riemann-equations-to-derive-the-derivative) as well if you have time ?

Answer (score 0):

Another hint: using $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ for $|x|<1$ solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I now got it! Could you give a hint for this problem as well (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853213/using-cauchy-riemann-equations-to-derive-the-derivative)?